# Delay a repeating animation in SwiftUI with between full autoreverse repeat cycles

Tags: swift, swiftui

I’m building an Apple Watch app in SwiftUI that reads the user’s heart rate and displays it next to a heart symbol.

I have an animation that makes the heart symbol beat repeatedly. Since I know the actual user’s heart rate, I’d like to make it beat at the same rate as the user’s heart rate, updating the animation every time the rate changes.

I can determine how long many seconds should be between beats by dividing the heart rate by 60. For example, if the user’s heart rate is 80 BPM, the animation should happen every 0.75 seconds (60/80).

Here is example code of what I have now, where `currentBPM` is a constant, but normally that will be updated.

```
struct SimpleBeatingView: View {
    
    // Once I get it working, this will come from a @Published Int that gets updated any time a new reading is avaliable.
    let currentBPM: Int = 80
    
    @State private var isBeating = false
    
    private let maxScale: CGFloat = 0.8
    
    var beatingAnimation: Animation {
        
        // The length of one beat
        let beatLength = 60 / Double(currentBPM)
        
        return Animation
            .easeInOut(duration: beatLength)
            .repeatForever()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .scaleEffect(isBeating ? 1 : maxScale)
            .animation(beatingAnimation)
            .onAppear {
                self.isBeating = true
            }
    }
}
```

I'm looking to make this animation behave more like Apple's built-in Heart Rate app. Instead of the heart constantly getting bigger or smaller, I'd like to have it *beat* (the animation in BOTH directions) then pause for a moment before *beating* again (the animation in both directions) then pause again, and so on.

When I add a one second delay, for example, with `.delay(1)` before `.repeatForever()`, the animation pauses **half way through** each beat. For example, it gets smaller, pauses, then gets bigger, then pauses, etc.

I understand why this happens, but **how can I insert the delay *between* each autoreversed repeat instead of at both ends of the autoreversed repeat?**

I'm confident I can figure out the math for how long the delay should be and the length of each beat to make everything work out correctly, so the delay length can be arbitrary, but what I'm looking for is help on **how I can achieve a pause between loops of the animation**.

One approach I played with was to `flatMap` the `currentBPM` into repeating published `Timer`s every time I get a new heart rate BPM so I can try to drive animations from those, but I wasn't sure how I can actually turn that into an animation in SwiftUI and I'm not sure if manually driving values that way is the right approach when the timing seems like it should be handled by the animation, based on my current understanding of SwiftUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution is to chain single *pieces* of animation using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`. This gives you control when to delay specific parts.

Here is a demo:

[image]

```
struct SimpleBeatingView: View {
    @State private var isBeating = false
    @State private var heartState: HeartState = .normal

    @State private var beatLength: TimeInterval = 1
    @State private var beatDelay: TimeInterval = 3

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .scaleEffect(heartState.scale)
            Button("isBeating: \(String(isBeating))") {
                isBeating.toggle()
            }
            HStack {
                Text("beatLength")
                Slider(value: $beatLength, in: 0.25...2)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("beatDelay")
                Slider(value: $beatDelay, in: 0...5)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: isBeating) { isBeating in
            if isBeating {
                startAnimation()
            } else {
                stopAnimation()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
private extension SimpleBeatingView {
    func startAnimation() {
        isBeating = true
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: beatLength * 0.25)) {
            heartState = .large
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + beatLength * 0.25) {
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: beatLength * 0.5)) {
                heartState = .small
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + beatLength * 0.75) {
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: beatLength * 0.25)) {
                heartState = .normal
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + beatLength + beatDelay) {
            withAnimation {
                if isBeating {
                    startAnimation()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func stopAnimation() {
        isBeating = false
    }
}
```

```
enum HeartState {
    case small, normal, large

    var scale: CGFloat {
        switch self {
        case .small: return 0.5
        case .normal: return 0.75
        case .large: return 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before pawello2222 answered, I was still experimenting with trying to get this working and I came up with a solution that uses `Timer` publishers and the Combine framework.

I've included the code below, but it is not a good solution because every time `currentBPM` changes a new delay is added before the next animation starts. pawello2222's answer was better because it always allows the current beating animation to finish then starts the next one at the updated rate for the next cycle.

Also, I think my answer here is not as good because a lot of the animation work is done in the data store object rather than being encapsulated in the view, where it probably makes more sense.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class DataStore: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var shouldBeSmall: Bool = false
    
    @Published var currentBPM: Int = 0
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        
        let newLengthPublisher =
            $currentBPM
            .map { 60 / Double($0) }
            .share()
        
        newLengthPublisher
            .delay(for: .seconds(0.2),
                   scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .map { beatLength in
                return Timer.publish(every: beatLength,
                                     on: .main,
                                     in: .common)
                    .autoconnect()
            }
            .switchToLatest()
            .sink { timer in
                self.shouldBeSmall = false
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        newLengthPublisher
            .map { beatLength in
                return Timer.publish(every: beatLength,
                                     on: .main,
                                     in: .common)
                    .autoconnect()
            }
            .switchToLatest()
            .sink { timer in
                self.shouldBeSmall = true
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        currentBPM = 75
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var store = DataStore()
    
    private let minScale: CGFloat = 0.8
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .scaleEffect(store.shouldBeSmall ? 1 : minScale)
                .animation(.easeIn)
            
            Text("\(store.currentBPM)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
    }
}
```